# MS SQL Server: Securing column level data

Tags: java, sql-server, security, encryption, hash

We already have an application being developed and now we want to secure(encrypting\hashing) the table columns in the database (**MS SQL Server 2008**). These few columns are like passwords, credit card numbers, SSN etc.

It is **Java** (1.5) based application and we are not using any api's like hibernate. Everything has been done from scratch.

I want to secure this data in such a way that it is not useful for anyone reading it. Can someone please advice how to do it (best practices) and what are the disadvantages in terms of performance?

Can this be done at database level (I am not talking about the whole db encrytion)?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

SQL server has encryption built in. Here is some sample code taken from my book about security (SQL Server 2012 Security Cookbook) :

```
USE marketing ;

-- create the database master key
CREATE MASTER KEY ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD = 'a very strong password';

-- a sample table
CREATE TABLE dbo.Customer ( 
    CustomerId int NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY, 
    Firstname varchar(50) NOT NULL, 
    Lastname varchar(50) NOT NULL, 
    CreditCardInfo varbinary(2000) NOT NULL 
) 

-- a certificate to protect the encryption key
CREATE CERTIFICATE KeyProtectionCert 
WITH SUBJECT = 'to protect symmetric encryption keys'; 

-- the symmetric encryption key
CREATE SYMMETRIC KEY CreditCardSKey 
WITH ALGORITHM = AES_256,
     KEY_SOURCE = '4frT-7FGHFDfTh98#6erZ3dq#«',
     IDENTITY_VALUE = 'l·Fg{(ZEfd@23fz4fqeRHY&4efVql'
ENCRYPTION BY CERTIFICATE KeyProtectionCert; 

-- using the encryption key
OPEN SYMMETRIC KEY CreditCardSKey 
DECRYPTION BY CERTIFICATE KeyProtectionCert; 

INSERT INTO dbo.Customer (Firstname, LastName, CreditCardInfo) 
VALUES ('Jim', 'Murphy', 
EncryptByKey(Key_Guid('CreditCardSKey'), '1111222233334444;12/13,456', 1, 'JimMurphy') 
); 

CLOSE SYMMETRIC KEY CreditCardSKey;

--To read the data and get back the original unencrypted data (the plaintext), we use the DecryptByKey() function: 
OPEN SYMMETRIC KEY CreditCardSKey DECRYPTION BY CERTIFICATE KeyProtectionCert; 

SELECT Firstname, Lastname,  
CAST(DecryptByKey(CreditCardInfo, 1, Firstname + Lastname) as varchar(50)) 
FROM dbo.Customer; 

CLOSE SYMMETRIC KEY CreditCardSKey;

-- or without opening it :
SELECT Firstname, Lastname,  
CAST(DecryptByKeyAutoCert(CERT_ID('KeyProtectionCert'), NULL, CreditCardInfo, 1, Firstname + Lastname) as varchar(50)) 
FROM dbo.Customer;
```